# Can't convert throwing to non-throwing completion block error

Tags: swift

I have an @objc protocol defined like this:

```
@objc public protocol MyDelegate: AnyObject {
  @objc func foo(
    completion: @escaping (FooResult) -> Void
  ) throws
}
```

where `FooResult` is:

```
@objc public enum FooResult: Int {
  case succeeded
  case delayed
}
```

I then have a service `MyService` whose function `bar` gets called with a completion block. This completion block is of type `MyServiceResult`:

```
enum MyServiceResult {
  case succeeded
  case delayed
  case failed(Error)
}
```

I need to be able to throw that error back from my delegate like this:

```
func foo(
  completion: @escaping (FooResult) -> Void
) throws {
  MyService.shared.bar(foo) { result in
    switch result {
    case .succeeded:
      completion(.succeeded)
    case .delayed:
      completion(.delayed)
    case .failed(let error):
      throw error // Can't do this!
    }
  }
}
```

However, it doesn't work because it complains:

`Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(MyService.MyServiceResult) throws -> Void' to non-throwing function type '(MyService.MyServiceResult) -> Void'`

How can I do this? Is this possible?
Because the delegate has to conform to `@objc`, I can't use an associated value with a failure case which is why I've decided to throw instead.

Comment: It's the method that throws, not the closure.

Comment: Yeah.. how can I propagate it to the method or is that not possible?

Comment: See: https://gist.github.com/myobie/e1842c329cd1c48c00029099a627ba33

Comment: @khjfquantumjj That's not for throwing from inside a completion block though...

Comment: it 's similar, your "execution block" `{ result in ...` is nothing but the inline function with signature `(whatever result type is) -> Void`